# Extract data from #document response

Tags: javascript, java

I have this controller in Java:

```
@Controller
public class Controller1 {

    //....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/demo/web/rest/post/create/bim/project", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Long createProject(@ModelAttribute UploadDescriptionFileDemo file, BindingResult result) {
        if (file.getName().trim() != "") {
            if (result != null) 
                file.setBindingResult(result);
            Long res = createProjectDemoSA.createProject(file);
            return res;
        } else {
            return EMPTY_NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it with ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url : url,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: "POST",
            data : formData,
            beforeSend : function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader(token.name, token.value, 'enctype',
                        'multipart/form-data');
            },
            success : (res) => {
                console.log(res);

            },
            error: (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

When I called this controller with ajax, all works fine and I get this response from the controller:

`#document
<Long xmlns="">200</Long>`

I want to get the value "200".

I tried to get this value by doing this in my ajax in the success part.

```js
let xmlDoc = $.parseXML(res);
let $xml = $( xmlDoc );
let  $title = $xml.find( "Long" );
```

But I didn't get the value between `<Long> </Long>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fiddled around with this code,
it appears you first need to remove the `#document` string (it is a part of the response right? since `ajax` returns string unless specified differently) and after that your code works.

in order to get the actual `200` into `$title` you also need to add:

```
let  $title = $xml.find( "Long" ).text();
```

so full code:

```
let xmlDoc = $.parseXML(res.replace('#document',''));
let $xml = $( xmlDoc );
let  $title = $xml.find( "Long" ).text();
```

this worked for me on this string:

`#document
<Long xmlns="">200</Long>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
The little problem is that 
`#document
<Long xmlns="">200</Long>` is not a string

Comment: are you sure? you `ajax` is defined so it returns a string... are you not getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I found the solution, I added `produces = "application/json" ` in @RequestMapping above the mothod createProject
So the controller return immediatly `200`